# can the maven maven-antrun-plugin plugin also be run similar to maven-install-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

Please refer to *[Plugin Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/plugin-info.html)*.

When using the antrun plugin in Maven, it looks like I am forced to define a plugin block in build/plugins. Also we need to define executions. In the example below, we're defining one execution tied to Maven's package phase.

E.g.:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ant-run-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>zip-artifacts</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <zip destfile="${project.basedir}/package.zip"
                       basedir="${project.build.directory}"
                       includes="*.jar" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is fine by itself.
However, if we look at *[Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)* and *[install:install-file](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html)* which is another popular Maven plugin. This plugin can is most commonly run like this-

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=your-artifact-1.0.jar \
                         [-DpomFile=your-pom.xml] \
                         [-Dsources=src.jar] \
                         [-Djavadoc=apidocs.jar] \
                         [-DgroupId=org.some.group] \
                         [-DartifactId=your-artifact] \
                         [-Dversion=1.0] \
                         [-Dpackaging=jar] \
                         [-Dclassifier=sources] \
                         [-DgeneratePom=true] \
                         [-DcreateChecksum=true]
```

Can the Maven antrun plugin also be run similarly without the explicit inclusion in pom.xml in plugins and configuring execution and typing to maven lifecycle phase?

If so, can you share an example.

Why would I want this? Let’s say am having a largely Maven-based project. However, there is some substantial work am also doing using [Ant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ant). I need to invoke Ant a few times. I also need to do Maven builds a few times to get this whole project to work. When I share this project to others I want to minimize the switch from Maven to Ant. I would rather they use just one build tool.

Comment: If you target is to use only one build tool you should convert everything to Maven... I don't understand why you need ant? For what purpose? Can you give more detailed information about that? `without the explicit inclusion in pom.xml in plugins and configuring execution and typing to maven lifecycle phase?` To answer that: No you can not...

Comment: Thanks. I suppose its still possible but not elegant even if possible. But gradle actually is better suited for this. In gradle the ant argets can easily be treated as gradle tasks. So I have started using gradle for this purpose.

Comment: The given example to create a zip file can be done via maven-assembly-plugin and Ant is not even needed... If you need to run install:install-file usually there is something wrong... because all your artifacts should be already uploaded to an appropriate repository manager otherwise your build will only work on your machine... which is a bad idea... Also if you need to run ant for particular things I doubt that your build is following best practices etc. but without more detailed information what exactly is being done with Ant I can help here...

Comment: How can I explain what i am upto.

Comment: Maven is great and often a lot easier than say Gradle. I do Love using Maven a lot. I am essentially extracting a particular application server. Automating its startup and configuration using ant. Building a few sample applications some of which are deployed in the server and some are not. This is a bunch of steps done one by one. Each step is automated mostly by ant. The few sample applications- they are maven based. When I delivered this it was appreciated but I got the feedback -they wish they had to deal with just one build tool.  Gradle is a harder beast but for this seems better

Comment: The question is old. My last comment is based on my experience after some time. But thanks for all the helpful comments.

Comment: `Automating its startup and configuration using ant.` this is not the job for a build tool... that sounds like more deployment job ... things like Ansible, or other tools like Chef, Puppet might be the right choice... or even a separate shell script or things like some go code might be better here... and separate build from deployment...

Comment: To some extent you are right. My audience was just regular developers. Didn't want to make them learn Ansible, Chef etc. I am actually impressed with your depth of knowledge. Thanks. :)

Comment: Might be the right time to setup a Jenkins (or alike) to handle the deployments... which results in a simple "Press that Button" for the "Devs" ;-) Or even automate that...

Comment: Maybe in the next phase. But did you look into gradle? The way it integrates with ant is also awesome. :)